# Rewrite DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I generate a pandas DataFrame from a dictionary. How can I get expected DataFrame?

The dictionary looks like this:

```
result = 
defaultdict(list, 76213.0: [76213.0, 97808.0, 377.0, 106118.0],
             133185.0: [133185.0, 132732.0])
```

The code I used to create DataFrame is

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index')
```

The output is like

```
            0     1        2     3    
76213     76213  97808    377  106118
133185    133185  132732  NaN   NaN
```

The expectation dataFrame looks like this

```
0           1
76213     76213
76213     97808 
76213     377
76213     106188
133185    133185
133185    132732
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! @WeNYoBen

Answer (score 1):

#### comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame([[k, v] for k, V in result.items() for v in V])

          0         1
0   76213.0   76213.0
1   76213.0   97808.0
2   76213.0     377.0
3   76213.0  106118.0
4  133185.0  133185.0
5  133185.0  132732.0
```

Answer (score 1):

With your df `stack`

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result, orient='index').stack().reset_index(level=0)
```